# Using constexpr as std::array size

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have the following code that uses a `constexpr` as the array size.

```
#include <array>

template <size_t size>
constexpr size_t
GetSize(const char(&format)[size])
{
    // Iterate over format array and compute a value.
    size_t count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (format[i] == '%')
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

template <size_t size>
constexpr auto
GetArray(const char(&format)[size])
{
    constexpr size_t arraySize = GetSize(format);
    return std::array<char, arraySize>();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    static_assert(GetArray("hello").size() == 12, "failed");
}
```

This however fails to compile under VS2019 with the following error

```
error C2131:  expression did not evaluate to a constant
message :  failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
message :  see usage of 'format'
message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'auto GetArray<6>(const char (&)[6])' being compiled
```

Is this a compiler bug? If so, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: For comparison: GCC 8.1 (linux) accepts without any complaint.

Comment: `arraySize` cannot be constexpr since format is not constexpr, I guess.

Comment: ICC and Clang also report that as an error https://godbolt.org/z/rqJ6RP

Comment: This issue has been described in great detail [in this FAQ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/7439261#7439261).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with constexpr functions is, that you can call the with both constexpr arguments as well as with non-constexpr arguments:

```
int constexpr f(int n)
{
    return ++n;
}

int constexpr n0 = 7;
int n1; std::cin >> n1;
f(n0); // result IS constexpr
f(n1); // result is NOT constexpr, just an ordinary int
```

Because of this characteristic the function parameters themselves *cannot* be constexpr, or more precisely, cannot be used in constexpr contexts. So in your function as well:

```
constexpr size_t arraySize = getSize(format);
//                                      ^ cannot be used as constexpr, even if
//                                        constexpr has been passed to, so result
//                                        not either (the f(n1) case above)
```

You could modify your second function a bit:

```
template <size_t Size>
constexpr auto
getArray()
{
    return std::array<char, Size>();
}
```

And use it like

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    static_assert(getArray<getSize("hello")>().size() == 0, "failed");
    return 0;
}
```

Sure, looks rather ugly now, you might hide behind a macro, though:

```
#define myGetArray(STRING) getArray<getSize(STRING)>()
```

or simply

```
#define getArray(STRING) std::array<char, getSize(STRING)>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you absolutely need the `GetSize()` function for some other purpose, but in your GetArray you already have access to the length of the array so you could just do this:

```
#include <array>

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto
GetArray(const char(&format)[N])
{
    return std::array<char, N*2>{};
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    static_assert(GetArray("hello").size() == 12, "failed");
}
```

Comment: I actually have to iterate over the format array to compute the size. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++17 working solution using lambda to wrap the char array as a constexpr.

```
#include <array>
#include <string>

template <typename Char_Array_Holder>
constexpr size_t GetSize(Char_Array_Holder holder)
{
  // Iterate over format array and compute a value.
  constexpr std::string_view format = holder();

  size_t count = 0;
  for (char c : format)
  {
    if (c == '%')
    {
      ++count;
    }
  }

  return count;
}

template <typename Char_Array_Holder>
constexpr auto GetArray(Char_Array_Holder holder)
{
  constexpr size_t arraySize = GetSize(holder);
  return std::array<char, arraySize>();
}

#define hold(msg) []() { return msg; }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  static_assert(GetArray(hold("hello")).size() == 0, "failed...");
  static_assert(GetArray(hold("h%ello")).size() == 1, "failed...");
  static_assert(GetArray(hold("h%el%%lo")).size() == 3, "failed...");
}
```

Adapted from [compile-time-string-parsing](https://blog.therocode.net/2018/09/compile-time-string-parsing) you can read to get futher information